# Problem in creating first laravel project. Below are php ,laravel installer and composer version details and error showing while creating project

Tags: php, laravel, installation

C:\xampp\htdocs>php -v
PHP 8.1.11 (cli)
C:\xampp\htdocs>composer -v
Composer version 2.4.2 2022-09-14 16:11:15

C:\xampp\htdocs>laravel -v
Laravel Installer 4.2.17

C:\xampp\htdocs>laravel new example-app3

Problem 1
- laravel/framework[v9.19.0, ..., 9.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^3.0.16 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.0.16, ..., 3.x-dev].
- league/flysystem[3.0.16, ..., 3.x-dev] require league/mime-type-detection ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.11.0].
- league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.0] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
- league/mime-type-detection[1.4.0, ..., 1.11.0] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^9.19 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v9.19.0, ..., 9.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\Program Files\php 8\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have tried many but couldn't resolved ... I am stuck at this error I have mentioned in question. How to run composer with --ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo  to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

Comment: "_Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension._" There's even instructions on how to do it

Comment: Why do you want to ignore that message? Why not fix it properly?

Comment: where to run the php--ini command to see files in CLI mode.

Comment: In your console/CLI/cmd where you ran `php -v`

Comment: C:\Program Files\php 8>php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\Program Files\php 8\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

Comment: Not sure why you'd run `php --ini`, that error message already told you which `php.ini` you need to edit: `C:\Program Files\php 8\php.ini`

Comment: extension=php_fileinfo.dll  I ,have added this command in php.ini and permision to change such things is not allowed in php.ini file...

Comment: " permision to change such things is not allowed in php.ini file" - what does that mean? Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Make sure you have the proper permission to edit this file. Maybe stop whatever server you have running before editing. Make your changes, save the file, restart your webserver. Good luck

Comment: @brombeer how can I enable the permission to edit php.ini file ..I have tried hard to enable the permission. and also how can I run Composer with --ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and did it like this.
B1: composer update --ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo (terminal).
B2: php artisan serve (terminal).
B3: generate app key -> refresh now.

Comment: I have run the above command in my terminal ,but at generate app key its telling command not found, what to do?

Comment: I have another solution . Remove ( ; ) before the line extension=fileinfo (path : phh/php.ini)

Comment: that file is not editable. I cant save it without ; ......can you tell me how to make this php.ini file editable?...one more thing how to  run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo`

Comment: I have remove that ; before the line extension=fileinfo (path : phh/php.ini) , and saved that file ..sussefully edited ,but still not working and showing same error.

Comment: yeh ! finally my problem was resolved ,thankyou everyone for guiding.

Comment: file can be edited with notepad++